# Hibernate: Unexpected "Cascading to persist on flush"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

tl;dr: Why does Hibernate try to persist a related entity although cascading is not enabled?

---

I have a many-to-one association with an intermediate entity:
A student has many courses; the association is saved in a table `students_courses`.

My Hibernate entities look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "students_id_seq", strategy = SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "students_id_seq", sequenceName = "students_id_seq")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = LAZY)
  private Set<StudentCourse> studentCourses;

  // ...
}

---

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "courses_id_seq", strategy = SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "courses_id_seq", sequenceName = "courses_id_seq")
  private Long id;

  // ...
}

---

@Entity
@Table(name = "students_courses")
public class StudentCourse {

  @EmbeddedId
  private StudentCourseId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("studentId")
  private Student student;

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId("courseId")
  private Course course;

  // ...

  public StudentCourse(Student student, Course course) {
    this.id = new StudentCourseId(student.getId(), course.getId());
    this.student = student;
    this.course = course;
  }

  @Embeddable
  public static class StudentCourseId implements Serializable {

    private long studentId;
    private long courseId;

    // all args constructor, no args constructor, override equals/hashcode
  }
}
```

(I tried to keep the example as short as possible; let me know if you need more information).

One of my Spring Boot services (using Spring Data) is trying to create a new `StudentCourse` entity using a *detached* `Student` entity:

```java
// inside a service method:
entityManager.detach(student);
studentCourseRepository.save(new StudentCourse(student, course));
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: <...>.Student; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: <...>.Student
```

When I look at the Hibernate logs, I can see that flushing the session triggers a cascade from `StudentCourse` to `Student`:

```
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushing session
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: <...>.StudentCourse
o.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction   : Cascading to persist on flush: <...>.Student
o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value: null
o.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState   : Detached instance of: <...>.Student
```

I do not understand why Hibernate cascades to the `Student` entity. I did not define any cascading and I thought that by default no cascading is applied. Why does Hibernate try to persist the detached student entity?